# Are GWT and Cappuccino running slow on mobile devices?

Tags: gwt, cappuccino

I've 2 questions:

1. Are GWT and Cappuccino web applications running slow on iPhone/iPad/Android devices ?
   Or is Capuccino much slower than GWT because it is not compiled ? Is GWT fast on mobiles ?
2. My idea is to develop the same app for the desktop using Cappuccino, and adapt the same code for iPhone and iPad (Objective-J is similar to Objective-C..).
   Is this a good idea ? Feasable ? Drawbacks ?

thanks

Comment: It's impossible to say whether GWT or Cappuccino "run slowly" without knowing anything about what the specific app is, or how it's written. It's possible to write slow applications in any language, on any platform.

Comment: @Jason Hall So, you are actually saying that if that the app is simple enough, it will run on mobile devices... or am I wrong ? I mean.. is reasonable to run Cappuccino apps on mobile devices ? Or is it designed for desktop computers ?

Comment: Yes, a reasonable desktop web app written in either of these frameworks will run reasonably well on modern smartphones as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two production GWT apps (one is using GWT-EXT and the other EXT-GWT ((GXT))) that I have tested on the iPhone. They both worked well on my old iPhone 3G and work even better on my iPhone 4.

These are not small apps and were originally designed for the desktop

Answer (score 0):

Cappuccino is compiled as well. Just run `jake deploy` before deploying. I believe the iPad app ["Air Forms"](http://polarbearfarm.com/airforms/index.html) is written in Cappuccino.